# RMarkdown Chunk - Don't echo last expression

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have a chunk in an RMarkdown document that looks like this:

````
```{r, echo=-4}
a <- 1
b <- 2
x <- a + b
print(paste(c("`x` is equal to ", x), collapse=""))
```
````

When I knit this, it doesn't show the 4th expression, as expected and as documented [here](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#text-results).

```
a <- 1
b <- 2
x <- a + b
## [1] "`x` is equal to 3"
```

However, if I add another line within the chunk, I have to update the `echo` parameter or it hides the wrong expression:

````
```{r, echo=-4}
a <- 1
b <- 2
c <- 3
x <- a + b + c
print(paste(c("`x` is equal to ", x), collapse=""))
```
````

Output:

```
a <- 1
b <- 2
c <- 3
print(paste(c("`x' is equal to ", x), collapse=""))
## [1] "`x` is equal to 6"
```

Is there a programmatic way in an RMarkdown Chunk to specify that you don't want to echo the *last expression* in a chunk without manually counting the total number of lines?

Comment: Move the print statement into a separate chunk and set echo=FALSE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a hack to do that: use [`knitr` hooks](https://yihui.name/knitr/hooks) to mark the lines to be removed of the output and remove them when printing output.
The following solution implements a new chunk option named `rm.last` that removes the `n` last lines of the source code.
`knitr` has a built-in chunk for source code, so you have to retrieve it with `knitr::knit_hooks$get('source')`.

````
---
title: "Hack the output with hooks"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_hooks$set(rm.last = function(options) {
  options$code <- 
    paste0(
      options$code, 
      c(rep("", length(options$code) - options$rm.last), 
        rep(" # REMOVE", options$rm.last)
      )
    )
  options
})

builtin_source_hook <- knitr::knit_hooks$get('source')

knitr::knit_hooks$set(source = function(x, options) {
  if (!is.null(options$rm.last))  
    x <- grep("# REMOVE$", x, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
  if (length(x) > 0) {
    return(builtin_source_hook(x, options))
  } else {
    invisible(NULL)
  }
})
```

```{r, rm.last=1}
a <- 1
b <- 2
x <- a + b
print(paste(c("`x` is equal to ", x), collapse=""))
```
````

However, if your last line of code is `print(...)`, you obviously have to follow @atiretoo answer.

Comment: Oops, a problem:  if the earlier lines have output, knitr breaks up the code into sections coming before each output.  `rm.last` will remove the last line of code from all of them, not just the last one.

Comment: @user2554330 I updated the answer after taking into account your remark. Thanks!

Comment: @romles Beautiful! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I like to do

````
```{r}
a <- 1
b <- 2
x <- a + b
```

`x` is equal to `r x`
````

Which gives a cleaner result output.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no way to do that.  If you look at the `knitr` source code, you'll see it gets a subset of the lines of code using

```
code = code[options$echo]
```

So it is using regular R indexing to select entries.  R has no way to say "last element" in a constant value or vector of values, so `rmarkdown` and `knitr` don't have a way to say "last expression".  Using @atiretoo's suggestion (just put it in a separate chunk) seems like your best bet.